# How to avoid getting password prompt while using SFTP?

Tags: sftp

Need some help on an sftp code I am working on. I added the public key of my `user@local_host` to the `remote_user@remote_server`. The key is added to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` on remote server.

What I expected was when I do `sftp remote_user@remote_server` from `local_host`, it to be password-less.
But it is still asking for the password for `remote_user@remote_server`.

I checked online, but most of the solutions have mentioned to use `sshpass` or `expect`. Unfortunately these are not installed on the local.

Am I doing something wrong in here? Help!

Comment: Provide the relevant lines from the SSHD service log on the service while the client is connecting

Answer (score -2):

According to the man pages, it uses the same information as ssh keys. If your ssh private key doesn't have a password on it, then you can do 1 of 2 things:

## On your local machine, (assuming linux) go to ~/.ssh/config and add the remote server to the list, as well as the key you're wanting to use:

```
Host my_remote_server
    HostName my_remote_server.full.address
    IdentityFile "~/.ssh/my_private_key"
    User my_remote_user
```

Host can be used as a short name, or you can pass the full server name, either will work.

### This would require you to put in the full address of the server every time you want to connect, in order for your key to be automatically selected.

```
Host my_remote_server.my.domain.com
     IdentityFile "~/.ssh/my_private_key"
     User my_remote_user

connect command: stfp my_remote_server.my.domain.com
```

### This would connect with the shortname, instead of having to type the full address.

```
Host my_remote_server
     HostName my_remote_server.my.domain.com
     IdentityFile "~/.ssh/my_private_key"
     User my_remote_user
connect command: sftp my_remote_server
```

### This one doesn't bake in the username, but lets you use the shortname.

```
Host my_remote_server
     HostName my_remote_server.my.domain.com
     IdentityFile "~/.ssh/my_private_key"
connect command: sftp my_remote_user@my_remote_server
```

## Another way would be to pass the private key in the command line

```
sftp -i "~/.ssh/my_private_key" my_remote_user@my_remote_server.my.domain.com
```